# Send email from app

Tags: android, email, notifications

I have developed an app where the user can enter an email address in the settings and on some specific event an email is sent to this address (as a notification).

The problem is: what is the best way to send an email from an app?

The best way would be to send an email from the google account of the app user but that isn't possible, right?

What I'm doing now is to do a HTTP post and send an email through php. This works great but since the app is used by many people the mail sending always gets disabled due to mass mail sending... What can I do?

Do I really need to host my own server?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Here you can found a very nice solution of sending email without user interaction :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

Answer (score 0):

I find sending emails to user without his interaction something similar to SPAM. I always choose the easiest and IMO honest alternative: just populate an `android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND` intent with calculated data and let user decide wether send the email or not always.